# syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end flash [:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this error which is not letting me look at articles that are created 
this is the error 
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end flash [:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"

image [image]

here are my codes
article_controller.rb file:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

   def new
     @article = Article.new 
   end
   def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)


 if  @article.save
  flash [:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"
  redirect_to_article_path(@article)
else
   render :new
 end 
end 
    private 
    def article_params 
       params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)

    end





   end




end
```

ask me for any other files if you need them

Comment: You have a ton of empty space here. Keep your code organized, as neat and tidy as you can afford, because sloppy code is where bugs hide.

Comment: sorry for that i will try better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to_article_path(@article), notice: "Article was submitted succsefully" }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
 end
```

Comment: This is a pretty aggressive reworking of the code, and while that's not bad, posting it without comment isn't as educational as it could be. This will likely raise more questions than it answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful when writing code, often every character counts:

```
flash[:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"
```

That space was causing the parsing to get all wonky.

What your code was being interpreted as was:

```
flash([:notice]) = "Article was submitted succsefully"
```

That's not valid Ruby.

Also: "succsefully" is not spelled right. Hope you didn't ship that yet!

Comment: i have edited please check

Comment: @ShashiYerra I'm not sure you even looked at this answer.

Comment: I have still got the same error except with parentheses around [:notice]

Comment: Do it *exactly* as in the first example with no space between `flash` and `[:notice]`.